# Take a full scrolling screenshot of a different page using Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, screenshot

How can I take a scrolling screenshot of a webpage with a different domain name using Vanilla JavaScript. The website should ask the user to enter a webpage URL. The website should then display a scrolling screenshot of that webpage.

I have an input tag and a button in my HTML code:

```
<input type="url" id="input-URL">
<button id="get-screenshot">Get scrolling image</button>
```

I have a div which should contain the scrolling screenshot of the webpage:

```
<div id="show-webpage"></div>
```

When the user enters a URL into the input box and presses the button, a scrolling screenshot should be shown in the div with the id show-webpage.

I have tried using the html2canvas module to do this. However, when I try to access a different webpage using this module, I receive the error:

```
Access to script at 'file:///file-path' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.
```

Through research, I have found that this is because of the CORS policy in other websites which stops my website from viewing the webpage.

How can I fix this error and correctly take a scrolling screenshot of the webpage.

I want to be able to take screenshots without needing to upload my website to a web server. The website should be able to run on my local machine.

Comment: The reason for _that_ CORS error is that you are not accessing your own project via protocol like HTTP or HTTPS to begin with, but are loading this simply via the file system - in which case _all_ such cross-origin requests will be blocked. But even if you access it via HTTP/HTTPS, that does not mean that just any arbitrary website you let the user input, will actually be "CORS-enabled" - so you would likely need a solution with a server-side CORS proxy to begin with then.

Comment: I want to be able to run this file without needing to upload the files to a server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) policy is a security feature implemented by web browsers that restricts web pages from making requests to a different domain than the one that served the web page. But...

You could use a proxy service like cors-anywhere (its only recommended for development projects):

```
const url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + document.getElementById('input-URL').value;
fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
        document.getElementById('show-webpage').innerHTML = data;
        // Use html2canvas or similar to take a screenshot
    });
```

Comment: Why is a proxy service only recommended for a development project and not a deployed project?

Comment: Because in production there are concerns about reliability, potential bandwidth limitations, added latency, and security risks. It's always safer and more efficient to handle CORS and proxy needs with your own backend in a deployment project.

Comment: How could I do this without the need for any other external tools which could break or be stopped?